# Multiplying Big-Ints in scheme-racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket, digit

I've implemented a "big-int" in scheme as a list, so the first element is the sign of the number (+ or -) and the following are the value of the number itself, first the ones, then the tens etc.

For example: `(+ 0 0 1)` is for `100`, `(- 9 2 3 1)` is for `-1329` etc.

What I need now is to implement addition, subtraction and multiplication for big-ints implemented in this manner. I've done addition and subtraction, can someone help me with multiplication, please?

Comment: If you've done addition, then multiplication is pretty straightforward (just follow the normal procedure for multiplication by hand on paper).

Comment: I thought so as well. But multiplication a with b is actually adding a to itself b times, but you can't convert bigint to its numeric value so you can't tell how many times to run add

Comment: I'm not talking about repeated addition, I'm talking about [long multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication).

Comment: The algorithm uses 2 for loops, scheme \ racket doesn't have for, but recursions.

Comment: You can still do nested loops in scheme. It sounds like this will be a good learning exercise for you. Good luck!

Comment: I understand what I need to do. but because the ints are saved as lists, it makes things much more difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the problem up into smaller pieces. First, write a function that multiplies a Big-int by a single digit. Then, extend this (using Greg Hewgill's hint that you probably know how to do this on paper) to a function that multiplies a Big-int by a list of digits.  Finally, wrap this in a function that accepts two Big-ints, strips off the sign, and then calls your previous function.

I strongly suggest that you write test cases for these functions before developing them.

Comment: I understand what I need to do. but because the ints are saved as lists, it makes things much more difficult

Comment: be more specific. Can you write a function that multiplies a Big-int by a single digit? If not, what step of the [design recipe](http://www.htdp.org/) are you stuck on?

Comment: I've written the function that multiplies a big int by a single digit. The rest is problamatic. Not to mention my addition function that I wrote eariler, that doesn't work at some cases - like when you have a carry to the next digit...I need help in those cases

Comment: Fix the addition function first; it's an easier problem, and you'll need it for this part. Second: let's say you've got a multiply-by-one-digit function and a working addition function. Now, imagine you're multiplying a number by 12. First, multiply it by one. Then, multiply it by two. Now: how do you combine these to get the correct answer?

Comment: OK I've fixed the addition problem and also got my 1-digit multiply function. As for your question, if I multiply a number by 12, first by 1 and second by 2, I can't recall how to get the final answer from there

Comment: Wait... let's be more concrete. You're trying to compute, say, 342 * 12. 342 * 1 = 342. 342 * 2 = 684.  How do you combine these to get the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

here is a well known divide-and-conquer approach to big-int multiplication:

http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/csbsju/cs/160/notes/31/1.html

This approach cuts the two numbers into halves and deals with them recursively. It is very fast, and it is easy to implement, despite the long explanation it may seem like. I highly recommend it. It takes all of about 10 lines of code in other languages, probably fewer in scheme :).

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm!!! Think about few points I ran into when implementing: The big int in this case is a list of the digits. How can you split the lists into halves? when there's a case that n = 1, even a simple calculation like a * b can be complicated in this case because a * b might be 2-digit result, and then a modification in the list required. Thanks again for the algorithm, though here's some things to think about. Any suggestions?